# Programmatically signing/encrypting Spring emails using GPG private-key

Tags: spring, email, gnupg

I am trying to set up a service which needs to notify users via email from time to time using Java + Spring Boot 3.0.2.
I want the service to be able to search online public-key stores for a recipient and encrypt the message or if no public-key is found, simply sign the message with its own key.

I am using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:3.0.2 and sending simple unencrypted/unsigned emails was up and running in no time using the org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage type.
However, I cant seem to find any library or method of properly integrating GnuPG public-keys into sending emails. There is plenty of examples of using GPG for files, text etc. but how to use it for emails eludes me.

I have a working POC using the org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage as message-type and org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl for sending the email.

I have not found a library or a clear description of how to manually sign/encrypt mail-content, which is the root of this question.